# OpenVPN: "ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2"

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN on Linux Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, which has been working correctly for more than one year until last Friday, when it stopped working.

Here's the OpenVPN log message I get:

```
sudo openvpn --config RDENFW-UDP4-1194-dchicco.ovpn 
2022-04-11 09:52:55 Note: Treating option '--ncp-ciphers' as  '--data-ciphers' (renamed in OpenVPN 2.5).
2022-04-11 09:52:55 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
2022-04-11 09:52:55 WARNING: file 'RDENFW-UDP4-1194-dchicco.p12' is group or others accessible
2022-04-11 09:52:55 OpenVPN 2.5.3 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jun 17 2021
2022-04-11 09:52:55 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017, LZO 2.08
Enter Private Key Password: *********
2022-04-11 09:52:58 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
2022-04-11 09:52:58 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]130.15.58.32:1194
2022-04-11 09:52:58 UDP link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:0
2022-04-11 09:52:58 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]130.15.58.32:1194
2022-04-11 09:52:58 [RDEN_OpenVPN_Server_Cert] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]130.15.58.32:1194
2022-04-11 09:52:59 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:4: block-outside-dns (2.5.3)
2022-04-11 09:52:59 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
2022-04-11 09:52:59 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
2022-04-11 09:52:59 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up
2022-04-11 09:52:59 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 local 10.251.251.70 peer 10.251.251.69
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
2022-04-11 09:52:59 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
2022-04-11 09:52:59 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
2022-04-11 09:52:59 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
2022-04-11 09:52:59 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
2022-04-11 09:52:59 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

And here's the `ovpn.conf` file content:

```
client
dev tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher aes-256-cbc
pull
nobind
reneg-sec 0
resolv-retry infinite
verb 3
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-random
remote pool-1.prd.ca.toronto.ovpn.com 1194
remote pool-1.prd.ca.toronto.ovpn.com 1195
proto udp
mute-replay-warnings
replay-window 256

comp-lzo

auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/credentials

ca /etc/openvpn/ovpn-ca.crt
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/ovpn-tls.key 1

log /tmp/openvpn.log

script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Any idea on how to solve this issue?
I tried already to restart the computer and also to run the command `sudo ip link delete tun1` but nothing changed. I also studied the other answers here on AskUbuntu but did not find anything that could relate to my case.